# Delete every pandas dataframe in final script

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, flask

I'm using pandas dataframes in different scripts. For example:

> `script1.py`:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_csv("textfile1.csv")
"do stuff with df1 including copying some columns to use"
```

> `script2.py`:

```
import pandas 
df2 = pd.read_csv("textfile2.csv")
"do stuff with df2 including using .loc to grab some specific rows.
```

and then using these two dataframes (in reality I'm using about 50 dataframes) in different Flask views and python scripts. However, when I go to the Homepage of my Flask application and I follow the steps to create a new result based on a different input file, the result keeps giving me the old (or the first) results file based on the dataframes it read in the first time.

I tried (mostly in combination of one another):

`- logout_user()`

`- session.clear()`

`- CACHE_TYPE=null`

`- gc.collect()`

`- SECRET_KEY = str(uuid.uuid4())`

```
- for var in dir():
    if isinstance(eval(var), pd.core.frame.DataFrame):
        del globals()[var]
```

I can't (read: shouldn't) delete pandas dataframes after they are created, as it is all interconnected. But what I would like is to have a button at the end of the last page, and if I were to click it, it would delete every pandas dataframe that exists in every script or in memory. Is that a possibility? That would hopefully solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with a class

```
class Dataframe1():
    def __init__(self, data):
      self.data = data
d1 = Dataframe1(pd.read_csv("textfile1.csv"))
```

If you want to access to the data

```
d1.data
```

To delete

```
del d1
```

Comment: I tried it out in the right script and it worked. Thanks a lot!